# Name for a company that resells products

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for a single word to call a company that does not manufacture products, but instead buys them and sells them again at a different price.

I came up with "reseller company"; is this a good description? Is there a better one?

Comment: Just plain *reseller* is perfectly normal. So is *retailer*. But much depends on context we don't have here. In the UK, for example, companies that sell new cars (but don't actually *make* them) are normally called *dealerships* or *distributors*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in comments,  *[reseller](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reseller#Noun)* (“a company or individual that purchases goods or services with the intention of reselling them rather than consuming or using them”) may be suitable.  If the reseller in some way adds value to a product (*eg* by customization) they are a [VAR](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=meaning+of+VAR&oq=meaning+of+VAR&gs_l=hp.3..0l10.2142.4247.1.4547.14.10.0.4.4.1.213.1574.1j7j2.10.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.o5jtC_U1Di0&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.cGE&fp=3bfbc8c558a01f89&biw=1053&bih=579), a  *value-added reseller*,  “a company that adds extra features to products it has bought before selling them on.”

When more- or less-specialized terms apply, they are more likely to be used, depending on context and custom.  These include the following (some of them already mentioned):
• *[retailer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/retailer#Noun)*, “A retail sales company or salesman”
•  *[distributor](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/distributor#Noun)*, “One who distributes”
•  *[broker](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/broker#Noun)*, “A mediator between a buyer and seller”
•  *[dealer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dealer#Noun)*, “One who deals things, especially automobiles; a middleman” or “A particular type of stock broker or trader”
•  *[trader](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trader#Noun)*, “One who gains a livelihood from trading goods or securities”
•  *[middleman](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/middleman#Noun)*, “An intermediate dealer between the manufacturer and the retailer or customer”
•   *[horsetrader](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/horsetrader#Noun)*, “One who is skillful in transacting or negotiating of any kind”